# Best way to describe changes in performance through time.

Tags: descriptive-statistics, median, mean-absolute-deviation

I'm wondering how to explain changes in production/performance metrics quarter to quarter. In the example below, one can see that the average processing time for "widgets" has decreased substantially over two years.  However, the last two quarters show a processing increase of 17%.   Given the long term trend, this really isn't significant.  What statistics would be best used in describing this?

[image]

Comment: Just looking at this chart isn't too informative. To develop a *statistical* estimate, more information is required that might help explain the evolution is processing time. Can you explain and elaborate on the component parts that went into this highly aggregated, summary chart? What are the "widgets?" What can you say about why processing time went from about 10 days to 14 days in the first three quarters and then fell to 8 days in the 4th quarter. What decisions were made that impacted this ratio? Etc...

Comment: The "widgets" are actually technical reports of varying complexity.  So far my explanations of any change have involved detailed discussions of the factors you mentioned.   The issue I run into is that auditors in upper management only look quarter to quarter, but I'm trying to figure out how to ascribe significance to these changes quantitatively, in addition to the  qualitative discussion.  It may not be possible given that each report can vary wildly in complexity and staff time.

Comment: Ok...try to put the information you just described into an Excel sheet--the idea being that you would build a small set of panel data where quarterly report level processing time is the target or dependent variable and the features driving it are quantifiable factors such as staffing (e.g., the number of people working on the report and the hours they bill), observable things that explain why the report is more or less complex from period to period, and so on. It sounds like this information would have to be gathered for each technical report. So, the matrix would have 10 rows for each report

Comment: At that point you could build a regression model with the dependent variable quarterly processing time and the various qualitative (e.g., report type) and quantitative metrics are the features or explanatory variables. This would decompose the highly aggregated info in the graphic you posted into its relevant component parts or drivers. At that point, you would be able to determine which factors are most (or least) important in their relative impact on processing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statistic/characterization/summary that you are looking for is "there has been a downward trend for the last 7 periods and the first 3 period were inconsistent with that trend' The TSOUTLIERS packages may be useful to generate this statement along with other commercial offerings that might even be more useful for short series like this one..

It's a poor Doctor that doest try his own prescriptions. I gave you 10 values to my toy of choice and lo and behold it concluded that there two distinctly different means and one anomaly.

[image]  . The identified equation (statistic) is [image] . Your statistic (%change) was descriptive and not inferential.

As @DJOHNSON pointed out you could build a causal model relating the # of gidgets to possible predictors. One would not be advised to simply use simple regression as you have time series data thus potentially (nearly always !) auto-correlated observations. The preferred method for dealing with causal time series data is called Transfer Function or simply ARMAX .

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a *causal* model. With only 10 quarters, does the OP have enough information to initialize an ARMAX model?

Comment: If he has the history of the causals , he could start with a simple OLS and review the autocorrelation of the residuals to perhaps identify any additional ARMA structure and perhaps some pulses which could lead to an enriched model. Ultimately he could check to see if the transfer functions model residuals were somehow coupled with lags of the X's in an attempt to identify/capture lag effects of the user suggested causals. This is how I would attempt to form a useful model with his sample size.